# PHPExcel reading a cell's format

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am having trouble finding out how to read a cells format.  I need to know if a cell's format is a date or not because when I read it into PHP it becomes a 5 digit number from excel.  I know I can take this number and then use PHPExcel to convert it into a PHP date but I first need to know that the cell I am reading is in fact a date cell.

I am wondering if there is a method like getCellFormat or something that I can use.

Thanks for the help

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')))
   echo 'Cell Contains a Date';
```

Comment: OK, can I use getCalculatedValue() to get the date the user sees in the excel sheet?  So to get 06/18/2011 instead of the 5 digit number.  The reason is because when I try and convert the excel number to a date I'm getting a different date than shown in the spreadsheet

Comment: Please give me an example of this... I've never been aware of any problems with the date conversion routines. If there is an error, I need examples.

Comment: getCalculatedValue() is used for formulae... but number/date conversion is formatting. Use the cell's getFormattedValue() method.

Comment: Hey Mark,  I can't seem to find that method, and I'm getting this error:  Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Cell::getFormattedValue().  Any thoughts?

Comment: I am using PHPExcel version 1.7.6

Comment: I got it thank you very much, was referencing all old library.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want the format code, presumably:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->getFormatCode();
```

You can compare this to the `PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat` constants, or some of your own regexes.